# MongoDB write concern for strong consistent

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have Java processes to update MongoDB 3.6.0. I have 1 - primary, 2 replicas. The flow is

1. Update some data in a document having a specific "_id"
2. Read from replicas

Sometimes, read gets an older version of the document.We decided to use WriteConcern to address this -

```
WriteConcern(WriteConcern.W3.withWTimeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).withJournal(false));
```

With the introduction of WriteConcern there will be some latency and to avoid too much latencies i skipped updating the Journal log

Is the above config going to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a high level view of the writing process:

1. Data is written to a snapshot,
2. from snapshot to journal ~0.1s
3. from snapshot to disk 1s

If you set up writeConcern = 3, and one server goes down, the user will never get an acknowledgment.

Also, disabling journaling won't fasten replication. I recommend to use writeConcern majority, and keep journal. But if you prefer to disable journaling, then the only problem would be data written between that 1s in **3.**

Comment: Thank you !! I am new to this, but I think Journalling is on by default and for one of the update operation we configured this WriteConcern and skipped writing to Journal. As we need strong consistency for this operation we used this config. If the server goes down then it will be a problem else it will work. Please correct my understanding

Comment: If you use writeConcern=3 and a server goes down, you never get the acknowledgement, cause you have only 2 servers up. If no server goes down, you're fine but I wouldn't relay on this. And **Yes**, journal is enabled by default and journaling isn't terribly important in systems where write concern is majority or larger, as long as the full stack of servers doesn't crash @sam

Comment: Thank you. In case of 1 server goes down I will not get the acknowledgement and the timeout error occurs. The 2 servers will have the updated data and there will be no rollback. Eventually when the 3rd server is up, won't the data get replicated in that node.